# Applying one useInView hook to multiple instances of the same component

Tags: reactjs, intersection-observer

I am trying to trigger animation for three instances of the same component stacked upon one another as soon as they come into view with useInView hook. When the component comes into and out of view (InView === true), a class will be toggled. However, as I scroll past an instance and reach the one below it, the system cannot determine if inView is true of false for the previous instance, and the class name is repeatedly toggled within it.  The following is my code:

```js
import classes from './Style/StyleImageContainer.component.module.css'
import { useInView } from 'react-intersection-observer'

function ImageContainer(props){
    const [ref1, inView, entry] = useInView({
        threshold: 0
    })
    return(
        <div className={props.direction === "left" ? `${classes.reverse} ${classes.right_part}`: classes.right_part}>
            <div className= {classes.verti_text}>
                <p ref={ref1} className= {inView ? `${classes.left} ${classes.return_to_original}` : classes.left}>Vintage</p>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.style_img}>
                <div className={classes.horti_text}>
                    <p className= {inView ? `${classes.horizontal_text} ${classes.return_to_original}` : classes.horizontal_text}>Distressed</p>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.image_container}>
                    <img src='/Photos/DSCF9924-Edit.jpg'/>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ImageContainer


import classes from './Style/StyleContainer.component.module.css'
import ImageContainer from './StyleImage.component'



function StyleContainer(){

    return(
        <div className={classes.style_container }>
                <ImageContainer/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default StyleContainer

function MainContent(){    
    return(        
        <div>
            <StyleContainer  direction="right"/>
            <StyleContainer direction="right"/> 
        </div>
    );
}

export default MainContent
```